# If services is running save to file if not save to another file

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to create a script, if a service is running it will save the Machine name and service to Running.txt file else the machine name and the service will be saved to NotRunning.txt

```
$comp = get-content -path "AllComps"

if(Get-Service -DisplayName "av*", "pri*" -ComputerName $comp | Where { $_.Status -eq 'stopped'}) {
    $_ | Sort-Object MachineName | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName |
    Out-File -FilePath 'NotRunning.txt' 
} else {
    $_ | Sort-Object MachineName | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName |
    Out-File -FilePath 'Running.txt' 
}
```

All my entries end up saving to the NotRunning.txt file.

I'm new to Powershell so any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `if` statement is always true since the `if` statement is checking whether `Get-Service` is true

Comment: How many services have a `DisplayName` that is matched by `"av*"` or `"pri*"`?  One?  Or multiple?  If _any_ matching service has a `Status` of `'stopped'` it will write only to `NotRunning.txt`, regardless of how many may have been `'Running'`.  I think you should be piping `Get-Service` into `ForEach-Object` and performing your `Status` check and file selection in there.

Comment: There is only one av/pri service on my work stations. If more I would put in the whole name. I'll give the ForEach-Object ago.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the condition of your `if` statement...

```bsh
Get-Service -DisplayName "av*", "pri*" -ComputerName $comp | Where { $_.Status -eq 'stopped'}
```

If that pipeline produces even just *one* service object, the whole thing will evaluate to `$true`.  Say, for example, there are two services on a given computer matched by your filter, and one is `Stopped` and the other is `Running`...

```
MachineName DisplayName Status
=========== =========== ======
Machine1    AV1         Running
Machine1    Pri2        Stopped
```

...because at least one service is `Stopped` your `if` statement will end up only writing to `NotRunning.txt`.  Alternatively, say those two services exist on three computers and all but one of those instances is `Running`...

```
MachineName DisplayName Status
=========== =========== ======
Machine1    AV1         Running
Machine1    Pri2        Stopped
Machine2    AV1         Running
Machine2    Pri2        Running
Machine3    AV1         Running
Machine3    Pri2        Running
```

...the same thing will happen and the five `Running` services will get masked by the one that is `Stopped`.

To fix this, I would use `ForEach-Object` to iterate over the resulting set of service objects, with the `if` statement inside of that to check the `Status` and write to the appropriate file...

```bsh
Get-Service -DisplayName "av*", "pri*" -ComputerName $comp `
    | Sort-Object MachineName
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        $outputFileName = if ($_.Status -eq 'Stopped') {
            'NotRunning.txt'
        } else {
            'Running.txt'
        }

        # Just write the service information as simple CSV output
        $_.MachineName, $_.Name, $_.DisplayName -join ',' `
            | Out-File -FilePath $outputFileName -Append
    }
```

Note that I changed the way the file output is built.  This is because `Out-File` is now being called once per *service instance* instead of once per *file*, so if I used `Format-Table` (or, say, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Export-Csv)) I'd end up with a complete table (with a new header and all) for each service row; `-Append` is needed so we don't end up with a file containing only the last service instance.

To allow us to use a record-based output with a header we can use the [`Group-Object` cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/group-object) to collect the services in groups based on whether the `Status` is `Running` or not...

```bsh
Get-Service -DisplayName "av*", "pri*" -ComputerName $comp `
    | Group-Object -Property @{ Expression = { $_.Status -eq 'Running' } } `
    | ForEach-Object -Process {
        # $_.Name contains the result of $_.Status -eq 'Running' above
        $outputFileName = if ($_.Name -eq $true) {
            'Running.txt'
        } else {
            'NotRunning.txt'
        }

        # $_.Group contains all of the service instances with
        # the same 'Running'/not 'Running' value for Status
        $_.Group `
                | Sort-Object MachineName `
                | Format-Table -Property MachineName, Status, Name, DisplayName `
                | Out-File -FilePath $outputFileName
    }
```

Thus, the `ScriptBlock` (`{ }`) passed to `ForEach-Object` will run at most twice: once for the service(s) with a `Status` of `Running`, and once for the service(s) where `Status` is [any other value](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.serviceprocess.servicecontrollerstatus).

Comment: You got love BACON, thanks for the detailed response, as someone just starting off with PowerShell this is way more helpful than someone just writing script solution. I wish I could give more than one upvote.

Comment: Thanks.  Yes, I think it's way more helpful, and maybe even should be expected, to actually _explain_ the problem and the solution rather than just saying "Here, copy-and-paste this code."